# Javascript setInterval doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I have this code that has to be a tree with random signs. I put setInterval to change the signs every second, but nothing happens and I don't get even any error.
Someone please tell me where I made a mistake, or more :).

```js
window.onload = intervalSetup;
function intervalSetup() {
 'use strict';
 setInterval(function() {
  theTree();
 }, 1000);
}

function theTree() {
 'use strict';
 var x = 8;
 for (var i=0; i<x; i++) {
  for (var j=x-1; j>i; j--) {
   document.write("&nbsp;&nbsp;");
  }
  for (var k=0; k<=(i*2); k++) {
   document.write(arraySigns[Math.floor(Math.random() * arraySigns.length)]);
  }
  document.write("<br>")
 }
 for (var i=0; i<2; i++) {
  for (var j=0; j<(x*2)-3; j++) {
   document.write("&nbsp;");
  }
  document.write("**<br>");
 }
}
```

Comment: Please do not edit your question such that it invalidates existing answers. Instead, create a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem was an undefined array, which was fixed in an edit.

The remaining problem was that the trees were being written to the page endlessly and it was hard to see the symbols changing.

By generating the tree in a container div which is cleared before each new tree, you can easily see that the symbols were properly random each time.

The snippet has a working example that functions by adding to the innerHTML of the treeDiv. (I took out the document fragment for readability)

```js
'use strict';
window.onload = intervalSetup;
var arraySigns;
var treeDiv;

function intervalSetup() {  
  arraySigns = ["*", "^", "&", "#"];
  treeDiv = document.getElementById("theTreeDiv");
  setInterval(theTree, 1000);
}

function theTree() {
  treeDiv.innerHTML = '';
  var x = 8;
  
  for (var i=0; i<x; i++) {
    
    for (var j=x-1; j>i; j--) {           
      treeDiv.innerHTML += "&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    }
    
    for (var k=0; k<=(i*2); k++) {      
      treeDiv.innerHTML += arraySigns[Math.floor(Math.random() * arraySigns.length)];
    }
    treeDiv.innerHTML += "<br>";  
  }
  
  for (var i=0; i<2; i++) {
    
    for (var j=0; j<(x*2)-3; j++) {
      treeDiv.innerHTML += "&nbsp;";
    }   
    treeDiv.innerHTML += "**<br>";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="theTreeDiv">
  
</div>
```

Comment: You did not answer the question, you made a new version. The question was "[…] nothing happens and I don't get even any error […]". A different approach is no answer, I think.

Comment: Thank you very much @Jecoms

Comment: @Mario The question changed from when it was originally posted. I answered with a working solution for the issue I gathered from reading the comments.

Comment: What can I say @Mario, I am not a js expert. I accept options too. Somehow u r right because I still don't know why my code didn't work in firefox, but in chrome did :).

Answer (score 2):

I tested the code on Google Chrome and it worked correctly.

Only had an `undefined` error in `arraySigns`.

[image: Image generate tree]

Comment: exactly it worked fine for me too...i could see the signs change

Answer (score 2):

The script has removed itself by writing to the document. That was the reason, the function was never called twice.

Funny bug, I think. :-)